# $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be twice differentiable , $f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x) , g(x) \ge 0 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ , then $f$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb R \to [ 0,\infty)$ be a function and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that

$f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x) , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ , then is it true that $f$ is bounded i.e. $\exists M \ge0 $ such that

$|f(x)| \le M , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

$f(x)+f''(x)=-xg(x)f'(x), \tag{1}$

we may multiply through by $f'(x)$:

$f(x)f'(x) + f'(x)f''(x) = -x g(x) (f'(x))^2, \tag{2}$

and since

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2)' = f(x)f'(x) + f'(x)f''(x), \tag{3}$

(2) becomes

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2)' = -x g(x) (f'(x))^2. \tag{4}$

Taking $x \ge 0$ for the moment, we may integrate (4) 'twixt $0$ and $x$, thusly:

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) - \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^x ((f(s))^2 + (f'(s))^2)' ds$
$=  -\int_0^x s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds, \tag{5}$

or

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) - \int_0^x s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds. \tag{6}$

It will be observed that, for $s \ge 0$, $s g(s) (f'(s))^2 \ge 0$, whence

$\int_0^x s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds \ge 0, \tag{7}$

and so from (6) and (7) we have

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) - \int_0^x s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds \le \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2); \tag{8}$

indeed, since $(f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2 \ge 0$, we may write

$0 \le \dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) - \int_0^x s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds \le \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2), \tag{9}$

for all $x \ge 0$.  Thus

$0 \le (f(x))^2 \le (f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2 \le (f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2, \tag{10}$

showing $f(x)$ is bounded for $x \ge 0$; indeed,

$\vert f(x) \vert \le \sqrt{f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2} \tag{11}$

for all non-negative $x$.  For $x \le 0$, we integrate *from* $x$ *to* $0$, *viz.*,

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) - \dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) =  -\int_x^0 s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds; \tag{12}$

re-arranging:

$\dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) = \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2) + \int_x^0 s g(s) (f'(s))^2 ds; \tag{13}$

for $s \le 0$, $s g(s) (f'(s))^2 \le 0$, whence $\int_x^0 sg(s)(f'(s))^2 ds \le 0$ and we again conclude

$0 \le \dfrac{1}{2}((f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2) \le  \dfrac{1}{2}((f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2), \tag{14}$

which as before leads to the conclusion that

$\vert f(x) \vert \le \sqrt{(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2} \tag{15}$

for all $x \le 0$ as well.  $f(x)$ is bounded by $\sqrt{(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2}$ for all $x$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Since since $-xg(x)(f'(x))^2$ is non-positive for non-negative $x$ and non-negative for non-positive $x$ , from $((f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2)'=-2xg(x)(f'(x))^2$ I think we can at once say  $(f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2 \le (f(0))^2+(f'(0))^2$ for any $x$

Comment: If you say that, which is OK with me, you are, if I am not mistaken, using assertions like: if $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \ge x_0$, then $f(x) \le f(x_0)$ for all $x \ge x_0$.  Well, how do you prove that?  I think the argument based on elementary integration is the easiest way.  Otherwise, you have to set up a more delicate argument using the definition of derivative and limits, if I am not mistaken.  I just though using integrals was easier.  Why not use arguments based on integrals?   Integrals are ***good***; nicer than derivatives.  Anyway, I see your point . .  . I think.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually you know I learned derivatives first , so it's kinda habit to use LMVT and all those when you can but off-course I am not saying Integrals are not okay :)

Comment: @user123733:  by "LMVT" you mean some form of the mean value theorem, right?  I guess such a proof could be constructed; it's just that I'm more familiar with integration-based techniques so that's what first popped into my mind, and so I went with it!  But I must say this is a very nice question!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer. The function $f$ is indeed bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. From 
$$
f(x)+f^{\prime \prime }(x)+xg(x)f^{\prime }(x)=0,\ x\in \mathbb{R}
$$ multiply by $2f^{\prime }(x)$ the equation, we get $$
2f(x)f^{\prime }(x)+2f^{\prime }(x)f^{\prime \prime }(x)+2xg(x)\left[
f^{\prime }(x)\right] ^{2}=0,\ \ \ \ for\ all\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
$$ then
$$
\left[ f^{2}(x)\right] ^{\prime }+\left[ \left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x)%
\right] ^{\prime }+2xg(x)\left[ f^{\prime }(x)\right] ^{2}=0,\ \ \ \ for\
all\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
$$ Now, integrate 
$$
\int \left( \left[ f^{2}(x)\right] ^{\prime }+\left[ \left( f^{\prime
}\right) ^{2}(x)\right] ^{\prime }+2xg(x)\left[ f^{\prime }(x)\right]
^{2}\right) dx=C,\ \ \ \ for\ all\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
$$ then%
$$
f^{2}(x)-f^{2}(0)+\left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x)-\left( f^{\prime
}\right) ^{2}(0)+\int_{0}^{x}2tg(t)\left[ f^{\prime }(t)\right] ^{2}dt=0,\ \
\ \ for\ all\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
$$ therefore%
$$
f^{2}(x)+\left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x)+\int_{0}^{x}2tg(t)\left[
f^{\prime }(t)\right] ^{2}dt=f^{2}(0)+\left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(0),\
\ \ \ for\ all\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
$$ Assume that $f$ is not bounded on $\left[ 0,+\infty \right) ,$ then there
exists a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}x_{n}=+\infty $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f^{2}(x_{n})=+\infty .$
Then, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f^{2}(x_{n})+\left( f^{\prime }\right)
^{2}(x_{n})=+\infty $ (because $f^{2}(x_{n})+\left( f^{\prime }\right)
^{2}(x_{n})\geq f^{2}(x_{n})\overset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow }%
\infty $). Since the right hand side is constant, then we should have%
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{x_{n}}2tg(t)\left[ f^{\prime }(t)\right]
^{2}dt=-\infty 
$$
which is impossible since the integrand function is completely positive on $%
\left[ 0,+\infty \right) .$ It follows that $f$ is bounded on $\left[
0,+\infty \right) .$ The same idea allows one to show that $f$ is bounded on 
$\left( -\infty ,0\right] .$ In fact,

Assume that $f$ is not bounded on $\left( -\infty ,0\right] ,$ then there
exists a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}x_{n}=-\infty $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f^{2}(x_{n})=+\infty .$
Then, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f^{2}(x_{n})+\left( f^{\prime }\right)
^{2}(x_{n})=+\infty $ (because $f^{2}(x_{n})+\left( f^{\prime }\right)
^{2}(x_{n})\geq f^{2}(x_{n})\overset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow }%
\infty $). Since the right hand side is constant, then we should have%
$$
-\infty =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{x_{n}}2tg(t)\left[ f^{\prime
}(t)\right] ^{2}dt=-\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{x_{n}}^{0}2tg(t)\left[
f^{\prime }(t)\right] ^{2}dt
$$
then%
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{x_{n}}^{0}2tg(t)\left[ f^{\prime }(t)\right]
^{2}dt=+\infty 
$$
which is impossible since ($x_{n}<0)$ and the integrand function is
completely negative on $\left( -\infty ,0\right] $ (there is $t$ inside). It
follows that $f$ is bounded on $\left( -\infty ,0\right] .$ Therefore, $f$
is bounded on the whole $
\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Do we have to use Integration ??

Comment: NO integration ! You have only to know that the integral of a positive function is a positive number, with no integral calculation. If it looks long, it is because it includes all the details, otherwise it is only two or three lines....

Comment: This argument, as does mine, uses integration in the most abstract sense--fundamental theorem of calculus, integral of a positive function is positive, etc.  No nasty integrals to evaluate, however!

Answer (score 0):

@user123733, You are right, it is possible to avoid completly the intergration. Here is an answer using your the idea in your comment which uses only
derivatives from Calculus 1.

Multiply the equation
\begin{equation*}
f(x)+f^{\prime \prime }(x)+xg(x)f^{\prime }(x)=0,\ x\in 
\mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
by $2f^{\prime }(x)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
2f(x)f^{\prime }(x)+2f^{\prime }(x)f^{\prime \prime }(x)+2xg(x)\left[
f^{\prime }(x)\right] ^{2}=0,\ \ \ \ for\ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
.
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
\left[ f^{2}(x)\right] ^{\prime }+\left[ \left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x)%
\right] ^{\prime }+2xg(x)\left[ f^{\prime }(x)\right] ^{2}=0,\ \ \ \ for\
all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\left[ f^{2}(x)+\left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x)\right] ^{\prime }=-2xg(x)%
\left[ f^{\prime }(x)\right] ^{2},\ \ \ \ for\ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
.
\end{equation*}
it follows that the derivative of the function definied by
\begin{equation*}
h(x)=f^{2}(x)+\left( f^{\prime }\right) ^{2}(x),\ for\ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
\end{equation*}
is of opposit $x^{\prime }s$ sign$;$ it is nonnegative for $x<0$ and
nonpositive for $x>0.$ This implies that the function $h$ is increasing in
the interval $\left( -\infty ,0\right) $ and is decreasing in the interval $%
\left( 0,+\infty \right) .$ Therefore, it admits a unique absolut maximum value at $x=0$
So,
\begin{equation*}
h(x)\leq h(0),\ for\ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{equation*}
f^{2}(x)+\left( f^{\prime }(x)\right) ^{2}\leq f^{2}(0)+\left( f^{\prime
}(0)\right) ^{2},\ \ \ \ for\ \ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
\end{equation*}
but,  $\left( f^{\prime }(x)\right) ^{2}\geq 0,$ for all $\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion%
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
,$ then 
\begin{equation*}
f^{2}(x)\leq f^{2}(x)+\left( f^{\prime }(x)\right) ^{2},\ \ \ \ for\ \ all\
x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion%
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
\end{equation*}
therefore
\begin{equation*}
f^{2}(x)\leq f^{2}(0)+\left( f^{\prime }(0)\right) ^{2},\ \ \ \ for\ \ all\
x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
\end{equation*}
which implies that
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert f(x)\right\vert \leq \sqrt{f^{2}(0)+\left( f^{\prime }(0)\right)
^{2}},\ \ \ \ for\ \ all\ x\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion%
.
\end{equation*}
The proof that $f$ is bounded on $
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}%
%EndExpansion%
$ is complete.